# How to add new layout below this layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

how to divide screen half?? how do i add image below this layout? this will capture full screen i want to add bwlow this layout one more layout which contain some textview or images  how i do that?  i want to devie full screen to half and add new latout below this layout how i do that?? like this image    https://i.stack.imgur.com/F56Yf.jpg  but screen look like this  https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFOBG.jpg

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/db1_root"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#333333"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"

    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:paddingLeft="1dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="CONTAINS"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="10dip" />





     <com.schoollunchapp.HorizontalListView
           android:id="@+id/listview"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="0dp"
              android:layout_weight="0.6"

           android:background="#ddd" >

</com.schoollunchapp.HorizontalListView>








 </LinearLayout>

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingLeft="1dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:text="kurdfgkjdfuhfudshfkdshfdfhs
 kdjhfjdshfkjdshfkdshfkshjdhfskjhfksdhfksjhfkjsdhfkjsdhfk
 jshfshfshfdshdfshdkjfhsafkjsahdfksahdf" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried putting the TextView in another Linear layout that is also nested within your container layout and given

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

? You can also check out [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216517/split-screen-in-two).

Comment: Basically, <LinearLayout ... android:orientation="horizontal"><LinearLayout ... android:layout_weight="1"> left content </LinearLayout> <LinearLayout ... android:layout_weight="1"> right content </LinearLayout></LinearLayout>  The internal linearlayouts should vertically fill parent and horizontally wrap content...